# How to extend the tensor construction over $\mathbb{Z}$ to one over a commutative ring $C$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules, tensor-products

Let $(E_1,\ldots,E_n)$ be a family of $C$-modules for some commutative ring $C$. Write $E:=\prod_{i=1}^nE_i$. Let $\phi:E\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}^{(E)}$ be defined by the equation $\phi(x):=(\delta_{xy})_{y\in E}$ for all $x\in E$.

Let $H$ be the $\mathbb{Z}$-submodule of $\mathbb{Z}^{(E)}$ generated by elements of the form
$$\phi(x_j+y_j,z)-\phi(x_j,z)-\phi(y_j,z)$$
for all $1\leq j\leq n$, $x_j,y_j\in E_j$ and $z\in\prod_{i\ne j}E_i$. Write $\bigotimes_{i=1}^nE_i:=\mathbb{Z}^{(E)}/H$ and let $\pi:\mathbb{Z}^{(E)}\rightarrow\bigotimes_{i=1}^nE_i$ be the canonical $\mathbb{Z}$-linear surjection. Finally, for $x\in E$, we write
$$x_1\otimes x_2\otimes\ldots\otimes x_n:=\pi(\phi(x)).$$

What is the most natural way to quotient $\bigotimes_{i=1}^nE_i$ in order to get a $\mathbb{Z}$-module in which
$$(\gamma x_1)\otimes'x_2\otimes'\ldots\otimes' x_n=x_1\otimes'(\gamma x_2)\otimes'\ldots\otimes'x_n=\ldots=x_1\otimes'\ldots\otimes' (\gamma x_n)$$
for $\gamma\in C$ and $x\in E$? Note that $\otimes'$ is the new tensor to be obtained.

Comment: Are you looking for an explicit description of the kernel? Or just a way to get to this desired module?

Comment: @OrangeMushroom I would prefer an explicit description--how else might one justify the existence of the desired module? Thank you for your help

Comment: The existence of such a module should be guaranteed by the definition of the tensor product for modules over general commutative rings, and it may be realized as a quotient of the tensor product over $\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 1):

Without bothering to find an explicit description of the kernel, we can use the universal property to move from one product to another. Specifically(letting the ring here be $R$ just because), consider the canonical $R$-multilinear map from $E_1 \times \cdots \times E_n \to E_1 \otimes_{R} \cdots \otimes_{R} E_n$ given by

\begin{equation*}
    (e_1, \ldots, e_n) \mapsto e_1 \otimes_{R} \cdots \otimes_{R} e_n.
\end{equation*}

Now, such a map is also $\mathbb{Z}$-multilinear, as in general the $\mathbb{Z}$-action on a module $M$ is given by a (unique) homomorphism $\mathbb{Z} \to \operatorname{End}(M)$, so it is equal to the composition $\mathbb{Z} \to R \to \operatorname{End}(M)$, which is to say that the action of any integer is given by an action of a ring element(this is more or less obvious). Thus by the universal property we obtain a (surjective) map $E_1 \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \cdots \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} E_n \to E_1 \otimes_{R} \cdots \otimes_{R} E_n$.